# Странное положение окна при вызове QMessageBox.question

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, macos

Пытаюсь вызвать модальный диалог с помощью `QMessageBox`

Мой код:

```
res = QMessageBox.question(QMessageBox(currentWindow), "Question",  "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```

Диалог открывается в непонятном месте, далеко от родительского окна currentWindow.

Такое же поведение прослеживается при других статических вызовах: `QMessageBox.warning` `QMessageBox.critical` и.т.д.

ОС: MacOS 10.12

**Вопрос: возможно ли заставить модальное окно открываться поверх родителя, а не где попало?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте указывать напрямую родителя (первый аргумент в методе):

```
res = QMessageBox.question(currentWindow, "Question",  "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```

Если вызов диалога происходит внутри вашего класса-виджета, то указывайте `self`:

```
res = QMessageBox.question(self, "Question",  "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```